# Ionic 2 Multilevel/Hierarchical select

Tags: angular, ionic2, treeview, ionic2-select

In ionic 2, how can I create a tree view select list? Previously in an web project I've used [ngx-treeview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview) and I want to achieve similar result ([Demo](https://leovo2708.github.io/ngx-treeview/)--example 1). I can use the same module but only problem is ionic doesn't support html dropdown and input. I couldn't find any ionic module similar to this either. Does anyone know something similar to this for ionic?

Comment: "ionic doesn't support html dropdown and input" ... what? The problem with using the same module is that you will need to add lodash ,bootstrap and font awesome , which is redundant in so many ways.  There should be no issue in displaying a tree view with a toggle on tap. The question is how do you want it displayed? because ngx-treeview is not mobile friendly so do you use ionic select .. or maybe trigger a modal with the tree data?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for multi level hierarchical component for ionic I have created and published one recently - see https://github.com/ryaa/ionic3-multi-level-select